# Fasting after miscarriage while bleeding

Tags: sawm

I got early stage miscarriage (6weeks) without fetus. So far it's happened more than 20 days. I am still got spotting blood daily. I would like to know am I allowed to do fasting & prayers? If the answer is yes, may in know what's the different between menstrual bleeding and miscarriage bleeding? And why during menstruation is not able to fasting but miscarriage is no problems. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

In https://www.dar-alifta.org/foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=8084
your desease is enumerated among the reasons that allow you not to to fast.
The general prescription is
al-Baqara 2:183-85

> So whoever sights the month, let him fast it; and whoever is ill or on
> a journey - then an equal number of other days. Allah intends for you
> ease and does not intend for you hardship and for you to complete the
> period and to glorify Allah for that which He has guided you; and
> perhaps you will be grateful.

See also
https://www.dar-alifta.org/foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=8083, also in case you decide to fast (in this case, ask a doctor).

Comment: Is miscarriage a desease? Please note that depending of the age of the fetus scholars either consider these spots equal to menses or childbed bleeding on one site or equal to an irregular menses (istihadah) and based on that she might either be allowed to fast and pray or not. I don't see any kind of discussion on this topic in your answer.

Comment: I am not a doctor in medecine and not making a diagnosis here. Not miscarriage, but post-natal bleeding for 20 days may be a desease. The fatawa 8083 describes istihadah as «bloody discharge that lasts less than a complete day», 8084 counts post-natal bleeding among reasons not to fast.

Comment: I don't know who is behind this dar-alifta', but if I were you I wouldn't pay a penny for their fatwa on this topic, at least it is very badly worded. Istihadah can mabye regarded as a disease or irregular bleeding (menses) that lasts more than 15 days! This is the definition the majority of scholars agreed upon based on the [Sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:320).

Comment: Dar-alifta is a highly respected institution linked to the Al-Azhar University in Kairo.